# Limit text field completion to a specific set of segments within Intellij Plugin

Tags: intellij-plugin

I was able to get code completion to work for a text field in my plugin based on the answer here: [Text Field with Standard PsiElement Auto Completion in IntelliJ Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443789/text-field-with-standard-psielement-auto-completion-in-intellij-plugin)

But that's only a part of the problem. In my field I need to express plain text plus Java expressions e.g.:

```
This is plain text and here's a Java expression {myJavaObject.myMethod()} here's more text and a variable {var}
```

This is a pretty standard concept in Java. I'd like completion and syntax highlighting to only apply within the curly braces. Is this possible? If so how would one go about implementing this?